# MAILTO: how can i only email the filled out inputs and options

Tags: php, html, forms, mailto

i have not used php before so i am unsure as to how this can be done, i have a very simple html form with quite a few option and input boxes but when i email the form it adds every option even the un selected values. Is there a way i can some how just send the values that have been changed or written in.  i shall put the link to my Basic website form and sample of the code below 
http://judithsstudentforms.netau.net/form.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>INVENTORY/SCHEDULE OF CONDITION</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="INVENTORY/SCHEDULE OF CONDITION:">  

    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="images/fav.png" type="image/png"/> -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <h1>INVENTORY/SCHEDULE OF CONDITION:</h1>
    </div>
    <form action="MAILTO:judmartin@btinternet.com?subject=INVENTORY/SCHEDULE_OF_CONDITION" method="post" enctype="text/plain">



    <div class="your-class">

    <select name="Address  " class="drop">
      <option value="  Not selected">Select Address: &#9660;</option>
      <option value="  2 Burlington rd">2 Burlington rd</option>
      <option value="  6 Sandhurst rd">6 Sandhurst rd</option>
      <option value="  7 Harborough rd">7 Harborough rd</option>
      <option value="  19 Harborough rd">19 Harborough rd</option>
      <option value="  38 Harborough  rd">38 Harborough  rd</option>
      <option value="  54 Newcombe rd">54 Newcombe rd</option>
      <option value="  72 Wilton ave">72 Wilton ave</option>
      <option value="  99 Wilton ave">99 Wilton ave</option>
    </select>

    <p>Room:</p>
    <select name="Rooms  " class="drop">
      <option value="  Not selected">Select Room: &#9660;</option>
      <option value="  down stairs front room">down stairs front room</option>
      <option value="  down stairs middle room">down stairs middle room</option>
      <option value="  down stairs back left room">down stairs back left room</option>
      <option value="  down stairs back middle room">down stairs back middle room</option>
      <option value="  down stairs back right room">down stairs back right room</option>
      <option value="  down stairs lounge">down stairs lounge</option>
      <option value="  down stairs toilet">down stairs toilet</option>
      <option value="  down stairs hall way">down stairs hall way</option>
      <option value="  down stairs kitchen">down stairs kitchen</option>
      <option value="  stairs">stairs</option>
      <option value="  up stairs front room">up stairs front room</option>
      <option value="  up stairs middle room">up stairs middle room</option>

    </select>

    <p>Walls:</p>

    <input name="wall description  " id="wall_condition" type="text" value="  " size="50"/> 

    <select name="wall condition  " class="drop">
      <option value="  Not selected">Select Walls Condition: &#9660;</option>
      <option value="  N/A">N/A</option>
      <option value="  Perfect">Perfect</option>
      <option value="  Slight signs of ware">Slight signs of ware</option>
      <option value="  Stained">Stained</option>
      <option value="  Cracked">Cracked</option>
      <option value="  Damaged">Damaged</option>
      <option value="  Dirty">Missing</option>
      <option value="  Drawn over">Parts Missing</option>
      <option value="  Dented">Defective</option>
    </select>

      <br>



    <p>Comments:</p>
    <textarea id="box" name="Comments   " rows="4" cols="90">
     Comments
    </textarea>
    <br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit_button">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset_button">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Submit the form to a php script and then send the data from $_POST array

Comment: or you can use `jQuery` to collect selected values and submit form by `jQuery` forcefully